# How to set relative path to font in apache-fop fop.xconf?

Tags: java, apache-fop

I have the following fop.conf, which works fine under Windows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fop>
<renderers>
<renderer mime="application/pdf">
  <fonts>
          <fonts><font kerning="yes" embed-url="/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
  <font-triplet name="arial" style="normal" weight="400"/></font>
  </fonts>
</renderer>
</renderers>
</fop>
```

But because the Application also needs to run on OS's which do not have Arial provided, I decided to add a the font to `src/main/resources/fonts/Arial.ttf` in the Java application.

So I'm trying to reference the font like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fop>
  <renderers>
    <renderer mime="application/pdf">
      <fonts>
        <directory>file:src/main/resources/fonts/</directory>
      </fonts>
    </renderer>
  </renderers>
</fop>
```

But it does not use the font.

While debugging I saw the fopFactoryBuilder has a field called `baseUri`, is it possible to add this to the fop.conf and extend it to get the path to the Arial font?

I don't have the fopFactoryBuilder.setFontBaseURL() because I need to use an older version which does not provide it.

What is the best way to provide the relative path inside the `fop.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fop>
<base>.</base>
<renderers>
<renderer mime="application/pdf">
   <fonts>
    <font kerning="yes" embed-url="app/src/main/resources/fonts/Arial.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
         <font-triplet name="Arial" style="normal" weight="400"/></font>
     <autodetect/>
   </fonts>
</renderer>
</renderers>
</fop>
```

Comment: But now the issue is when this is running on the Server it cannot find the font. On local machine this works because obviously the whole project is on the local machine.